# Linearly interpolate elevation between two x,y,z points

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I am attempting to get an elevation value between to x,y,z points. Using scipy.interpolate.interp2d, like so:

```
x = np.array((140.865, 140.863))
y = np.array((59.8817, 59.8814))
z = np.array((121, 127))
f = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x,y,z, kind="linear")
z_new = f(140.864,59.58816)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: m >= (kx+1)(ky+1) must hold
```

I have not found clear documentation for this type error. Perhaps I am using too few data points for interp2d?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html):

> The minimum number of data points required along the interpolation
> axis is (k+1)**2, with k=1 for linear, k=3 for cubic and k=5 for
> quintic interpolation.

And since you use `linear`, (1+1)**2=4, and you unfortunately only supplied two data points.

Comment: Thanks! This explains the type error. Considering this limitation of interp2d, how might one achieve this simple interpolation?

Comment: I would recommend checking out a very similar question to yours, and the answer, at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/251519 .

Comment: 2 points is insufficient to define a plane so your question is mathematically ill-posed unless the 3 points are colinear.